# In React and React Router, how to display a header on every page except home page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm new to React, using react@16.0.0 and react-router-dom@4.2.2.

I am displaying a footer on every page. I would like to display a header on every page except the home page but I don't know where to start.

My current app.jsx looks like the following:

```
export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                    <Route exact path="/download" component={DownloadPage} />
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React setting up a one-off route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46936988/react-setting-up-a-one-off-route)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React Router will render **all** routes that match a given path, since you're not using a switch. So its a simple matter of providing a route and a passing a render to it.

e.g.

`<Route path="/" render={ ( props ) => ( props.location.pathname !== "/") && <Header /> }>`

replace the props.location.pathname check where it has '/' with whatever you want (/home for example) and it won't render the  component for that route.

```
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route path="/" render={ ( props ) => ( props.location.pathname !== "/") && <Header /> }>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <Route exact path="/download" component={DownloadPage} />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much.